# How to display title of a webform in twig template Drupal 8

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I want to display webform title in a `webform.html.twig` but I did not find anything in `variables` array regarding the title of the webform

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_webform($variables){
  $title = "?";
}
```

How do I get webform title in a preprocess function ? Any suggestions or other approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I came up with

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_webform(&$vars){
  $wfid = $vars["element"]["#webform_id"];
  $wf = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($wfid);
  $vars["title"] = $wf->label();
}
```

Then in your theme's `webform.html.twig` you can use `{{title}}`

Comment: That is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks coming from you I take it its true ... wouldn't it make sense for webform to include it in the variables array for preprocessors to consume ?

Comment: The webform.twig.html template just renders the form does not really need to include the {{ title }}. https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/templates/webform.html.twig

Comment: It doesn't *need* it, but if you `dump(_context|keys)` you'll see that it does have all the other makings necessary to have a working `{{title}}` field including `{{ title_attributes }}` as well as the less related misnomer `{{ title_prefix }}` and `{{ title_suffix }}`, so there is no reason *not* to pass the variable to the template, even if not used by default. I want to file this as a TX bug.